# RSA Certificate Error Starting MySQL 5.7 on CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, centos

We've been getting some trouble installing MySQL 5.7 on a CentOS 6 box. Information about the environment is available below:

CentOS Version:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

MySQL Version:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Installation of the product went smoothly, using the RPM Bundle that is avaliable on MySQL's website. The thing is when we try to start the service, it fails with the following error on the log:

```
2020-05-07T23:30:15.740642Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2020-05-07T23:30:15.843684Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-05-07T23:30:15.908471Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: b4c0fbe7-90ba-11ea-bb12-0274ede54730.
2020-05-07T23:30:15.911056Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-07T23:30:15.914313Z 0 [ERROR] Could not generate RSA private key required for X509 certificate.
2020-05-07T23:30:15.914355Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

After some research, we were able to find the `mysql_ssl_rsa_setup` command which generates the certificates on the MySQL data folder, but after starting the server again, since it is the first time it initializes, it validates the emptyness of the data folder and hangs on the initialization phase:

```
Initializing MySQL database:  2020-05-08T13:31:31.308631Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2020-05-08T13:31:31.308718Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This basically means we are stuck on a loop and can't start the service. OpenSSL is properly installed on the latest version provided by CentOS 6:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]# openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL>
```

The MySQL documentation is kind of poor on this error and we even tried to use the option to skip the ssl certificates creation and later create them, but with no success.

Has anyone seen this error on the wild and can share some insight?

Thanks!

Comment: you are using a mariadb server and see thos for more inofrmation where you find all the necessary information https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/

Comment: @nbk I'm not using a MariaDB server.

Comment: It doesn't matter MySQL and mariadb are using the same configurations so do what is written in the link